# Example of jquery easing plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
easeOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
    }
```

At this line of code on jquery easin plugin, How we want to know the value if `x, t, b, c, d`  in parentheses.I'm just wanna know What there are doing..?

Answer (score 2):

At the top of the script there is a line commented out that says:

```
// t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
```